# How should I call my function inside map method?

Tags: javascript

I want to use function instead of codes that I wrote in map method and I want to call this function (createItemCart) inside map method but I don't know how to do it.

This is createItemCart function:

```
  const product = event.target.parentElement;
  const id = product.id;
  const imgProduct = product.querySelector("img").src;
  const titleProduct = product.querySelector(".title").innerText;
  const priceProduct = Number(product.querySelector(".price").innerText);
  const qtyCheck = document.getElementById("item" + id);
  let totalPrice = Number(document.querySelector(".total-price").innerText);
  document.querySelector(".total-price").innerText = totalPrice + priceProduct;

function createItemCart(imgProduct, titleProduct, priceProduct, totalPrice, id) {
  const itemsCart = document.getElementById("items-cart");
  document.querySelector(".total-price").innerText = totalPrice + priceProduct;
  
  const item = document.createElement("div");
  item.setAttribute("class", "item-cart");

  const imgItem = document.createElement("img");
  imgItem.src = imgProduct;

  const detailItem = document.createElement("div");

  const titleItem = document.createElement("div");
  titleItem.setAttribute("class", "title-item");
  titleItem.innerText = titleProduct;

  const divPrice = document.createElement("div");

  const priceItem = document.createElement("span");
  priceItem.setAttribute("class", "price-item");
  priceItem.innerText = priceProduct;

  const spanToman = document.createElement("span");
  spanToman.innerText = "تومان";

  const qtyItem = document.createElement("div");
  qtyItem.className = "qty-item";
  qtyItem.innerText = "1";
  qtyItem.id = "item" + id;

  const deleteItem = document.createElement("i");
  deleteItem.className = "delete-item";
  deleteItem.innerText = "x";

  deleteItemCart(deleteItem, totalPrice, priceProduct);

  detailItem.appendChild(titleItem);
  detailItem.appendChild(divPrice);
  detailItem.appendChild(qtyItem);
  divPrice.appendChild(priceItem);
  divPrice.appendChild(spanToman);
  item.appendChild(imgItem);
  item.appendChild(detailItem);
  item.appendChild(deleteItem);

  itemsCart.appendChild(item);
}
```

This is map method:

```
    items.map((itemCart) => {
      const item = document.createElement("div");
      item.setAttribute("class", "item-cart");

      const imgItem = document.createElement("img");
      imgItem.src = itemCart.img;

      const detailItem = document.createElement("div");

      const titleItem = document.createElement("div");
      titleItem.setAttribute("class", "title-item");
      titleItem.innerText = itemCart.title;

      const divPrice = document.createElement("div");

      const priceItem = document.createElement("span");
      priceItem.setAttribute("class", "price-item");
      priceItem.innerText = itemCart.price;

      const spanToman = document.createElement("span");
      spanToman.innerText = "تومان";

      const qtyItem = document.createElement("div");
      qtyItem.className = "qty-item";
      qtyItem.innerText = itemCart.qty;
      qtyItem.id = "item" + itemCart.id;

      totalPrice += itemCart.price * itemCart.qty;
      document.querySelector(".total-price").innerText = totalPrice;
      sumQty += itemCart.qty;
      document.getElementById("number").innerText = sumQty;

      const deleteItem = document.createElement("i");
      deleteItem.className = "delete-item";
      deleteItem.innerText = "x";
      deleteItemCart(deleteItem, totalPrice, itemCart.price);

      detailItem.appendChild(titleItem);
      detailItem.appendChild(divPrice);
      detailItem.appendChild(qtyItem);
      divPrice.appendChild(priceItem);
      divPrice.appendChild(spanToman);
      item.appendChild(imgItem);
      item.appendChild(detailItem);
      item.appendChild(deleteItem);

      itemsCart.appendChild(item);
    });
```

For example I don't know how to use itemCart.img in createItemCart Function. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `itemCart.img` in the function, you use it as the argument to the function.

```
items.forEach(itemCart => 
    createItemCart(itemCart.img, itemCart.title, itemCart.price, itemCart.price * itemCart.qty, itemCart.id));
```

And you should use `forEach()` rather than `map()`. `map()` is used when you want to create an array of the results of the function, but your function doesn't return anything.